# Is it possible to match several independent regexes in one regex?

Tags: regex, string

Let's say I want to match "string should be between 2 and 8 characters", I would use the regex `/^.{2,8}$/`

Now if I wanted to match "string should contain at least one digit", I would use the regex `/\d/`

And finally if I wanted to match "string should contain at least one capital letter", I would use `/[A-Z]/`

But now I wonder, would it be possible to match a string to all those conditions in one regex? And I don't mean in an OR fashion, I mean in an AND fashion.

Comment: So a RE for *one or more digits and capital letters with a total length of 2>8* ?

Comment: @AlexK. in this case yes. I want to know how to do it in a generalized way, but I made up this example to make it more concrete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z]).{2,8}$
```

Explanation:

- `(?=.*\d)` look ahead for at least one digit
- `(?=.*[A-Z])` look ahead for at least one capital letter
- `.{2,8}` the actual match

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/eC8zS9/2)

**Old answer**

```
^(?=.*\d.*[A-Z]).{2,8}$|^(?=.*[A-Z].*\d).{2,8}$
```

Explanation:

- `(?=.*\d.*[A-Z])` look ahead for at least one digit followed by one capital letter
- `.{2,8}` actual match or
- `(?=.*[A-Z].*\d)` look ahead for at least one capital letter followed by one digit
- `.{2,8}` actual match

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/eC8zS9/1)

Comment: @Evert Welcome.. and I just realized the answer can be simplified and generalized.. check the update.. :)